# Is there any anti-theft / robber-spy application on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch, security, camera

theft application on Ubuntu Touch Saucy which could help protect my tablet/phone ?

I mean an application running as daemon on back-end and waiting for remote activation. Activated by an GPS event, GSM cell name, text/script on website, trough my private VPN or by remote shell connection, or user behavioural pattern.
Application logging GPS location, sending photos from the front-end camera, streaming sound, watching public wifi hotspots to send the data to home.

All in accordance with the law, but actively.
Only in case of theft of my lovely gadget.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu touch is still on development. The applications that will be in the final version are still being developed, or are in the planning steps.

The only way to know is checking the [Blueprints](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone-coreapps), which includes all the *current* applications.

I didn't see a specific app about this, you can ask in the Developers Community G+ page:

> Questions? if you've got any questions about this collection of Ubuntu Touch apps, or about app development in Ubuntu, you can join and [ask our community of developers.](https://plus.google.com/communities/111350780270925540549)